# Xamarin Test Recoder for Visual studio not working

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android

I use Visual Studio  2015  Enterprise. I use trial Xamarin Cloud.  I installed Test Recoder for VS. I read this [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/visual-studio/).  I do not see in the editor icon Test Recoder.  How do I run Test Recoder for VS?

Comment: Are you properly logged into VS?

Comment: Yes, I logged in VS

Comment: I installed last version Test Recoder (0.4). But it is not work. Anybody uses it?

Comment: Not with VS. On a Mac I launch it as a separate application. Have you tried that?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have mac. I need Test Recoder for Visual Studio.

Comment: I installed last version Test Recoder (0.4.1). But it is not work.

Comment: I installed last version 0.4.2. It is work -I see icon. But I get error "failed connection to app" when I chose apk.